# Why Can't I See Value In Immediate Window?

Tags: c#, directory

I have a snippet of code that will traverse a directory location and create a data model from it.  For example, if I have a directory structure:

```
c:\TestDir1

c:\TestDir1\Sub1\
c:\TestDir1\Sub1\File1.txt
c:\TestDir1\Sub1\File2.txt

c:\TestDir1\Sub1\SubSub1
c:\TestDir1\Sub1\SubSub1\File3.xlsx

c:\TestDir1\Sub1\SubSub1\SubDirX
c:\TestDir1\Sub1\SubSub1\SubDirX\File4.txt
c:\TestDir1\Sub1\SubSub1\SubDirX\File5.txt
c:\TestDir1\Sub1\SubSub1\SubDirX\File6.txt
```

It will create the appropriate data model via the following code:

```
static void BeginIt()
{
    DirectoryInfo diTop = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\Misc\3) Projects\002) Document Manager\DirectoryReading\TestDir1");
    string path = diTop.FullName;
    MySubDir mySubDir = new MySubDir(path);
}

public class MySubDir
{
    public ArrayList _dirs;
    public ArrayList _files;

    public MySubDir(string dirPath)
    {
        _dirs = new ArrayList();
        _files = new ArrayList();
        this.ProcessDirectory(dirPath);
    }

    private void ProcessDirectory(string dirPath)
    {
        // Process the list of files found in the directory.
        string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(dirPath);
        foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
        {
            _files.Add(fileName);
        }

        // Recurse into subdirectories of this directory.
        string[] subdirectoryEntries = Directory.GetDirectories(dirPath);

        foreach (string subdirectory in subdirectoryEntries)
        {
            _dirs.Add(new MySubDir(subdirectory));
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my question.  When I step through the code line by line it is building up the data model appropriately.  When I do an AddWatch I can see the object and the directory structure is built up properly.

When I try to access the value of the contents via the Immediate Window I get errors.  For example if I type the following into the immediate window the following

? mySubDir._dirs[0]._dirs[0]

I get an error.

How do I get at the values of these subdirectories?  I would like to be able to access the directory names and filenames of the elements in this model now that it is created.

Thanks

Comment: When you get an error, a) try reading it very carefully - it may contain clues to the problem, and b) If you're going to mention it in a question, *include* the actual error information - even if you cannot glean any useful information from it, maybe your would-be answerers can?

Comment: In addition: if you're going to mention accessing things in the immediate window, also indicate *where* you've stopped execution (e.g. add a comment into the source saying `<-- Breakpoint here`, or similar)

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't look like it would work, since the expression `mySubDir.whatever` depends on `mySubDir` being in scope and having a valid value. In order for that to happen, the constructor has to return *first* -- but the object is being populated *during* the execution of the constructor. So there's really no point during the lifetime of this program that such an expression would yield a meaningful result.

If you break into the debugger inside the `ProcessDirectory` method, you can use `this._dirs` to have a look into the data structure.

Apart from that, `ArrayList` is not the best choice for a collection that you know from beforehand will contain just `string`s, like the ones you have here. It would be more appropriate to define those as `System.Collections.Generic.List<string>`.

Answer (score 0):

well.. _dirs and files are arraylist.. so you might want to transverse that list and get all the values. a for, an enumerator, a linq or whatever method you like will do the trick..

Update:

After reading some more your post, I think there is a problem of basic understand. Adding just names to the class, will not give you the file position or it folder. You will have to look for a better way to use it (maybe a class folder/files that can hold folders also?)..

Answer (score 0):

_dirs is an ArrayList which stores objects so you need to cast the object from the first _dir[0] to a MySubDir

e.g.

```
((MySubDir)mySubDir._dir[0])._dir[0]
```

Either that or change the collection type from ArrayList to

```
List<MySubDir>
```

this will give you strongly typed list items when accessed with the indexer.